# Get public key hash from cer certificate in Android

Tags: java, android, kotlin, openssl, public-key

I have a cer certificate stored in my raw folder. I need to extract the public key hash from it.

I tried in the terminal and it gives correct public key hash using following command.

```
Terminal command: openssl x509 -inform DER -in certificate.cer -pubkey -noout > pubkey.pem
```

Above command gives me the correct public key hash in the format I required,

```
Eg output: beAmI30qZXmIu44J8J1KYe0Uzoqq1ZF699W8HnP0ZZk=
```

As my requirement I tried to extract this key from my certificate in raw folder using following code,

```
fun getCertificate(): InputStream {
    val inputStream = App.applicationContext().resources.openRawResource(
        App.applicationContext().resources.getIdentifier(
            "certificate",
            "raw", App.applicationContext().packageName
        )
    )
    return inputStream
}

fun getPublicKey(): String {
    val f: CertificateFactory = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509")
    val certificate: X509Certificate =
        f.generateCertificate(getCertificate()) as X509Certificate
    val pk: PublicKey = certificate.getPublicKey()

    val publicKeyString = Base64.encodeToString(pk.encoded, Base64.DEFAULT)

    Log.d(TAG, "PublicKey: $publicKeyString")

    return publicKeyString
}
```

Output in logcat:

```
PublicKey: MIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEAyMl/U/9qHgD5PaL1UlVKAiVCmT73B/Fs
fnfoUhl12/ko2w+a5MKEQJnMlqO2yhl6M0p+ZBn/8mBcw0QxjHbn5qW2aZ5wXzFfkgTxV+bBBYdu
eDKuEU18FFoUvasdasdasdsadasdadadadsdadsdsadwDgdtzQYm7CUtPzgO4HvqZX7LBv1BaIgI
j8OMW1sCkhk0ZYNQzGRcxlu2Q5vjPU4hUpw25YWAE4NotoTOAxcg8DgjnSvsFp2hUZemxbd2bBSB
fgDlla4oopsCsZ3RRb4qHHJGShdskajdgskajdaskdjahslkjrB1YBWGzlvCw93Z0ayA
EWUdWwIDAQAB
```

As you can see the public key hash I received is different from one I required. How can I achieve the same thing as the terminal command in openssl?

Note 1: I have changed public key texts to avoid exposing the key however pattern is similar.

Note 2: Kotlin or Java both answers are accepted I just need the correct api/method

Comment: I don't see where in your Kotlin code you generate the hash, instead you are printing the complete public key, unhashed.

Answer (score 1):

As @Robert pointed out in the comment section I wasn't hashing my output. I resolved it with the hashing method. Nice catch :)

Posting the answer here so others can use this question and answer to get the hashkey from cer.

```
fun calculateSH256(secret: ByteArray): String {
    val sha256hex = Hashing.sha256().hashBytes(secret).asBytes()
    return Base64.encodeToString(sha256hex, Base64.DEFAULT)
}
```